# GitHub上のPull RequestにReviewerを追加したい

Tags: github

GitHubのpull request でレビューを依頼する相手はどう指定すれば良いのですか？

Git、GitHubについて学習しています。2台のPCと各々にGitHubアカウントを作成しました。

自分（メイン）のGitHubアカウントでリポジトリを作成(git_tutorial)し、ローカルの端末へclone で移した後にブランチを切ったりファイルに変更を加え git push origin ～のコマンドを打ちました。

ここでその変更のレビューを依頼する、つまりpull requestを行いたいと思います。
そこでレビューをする相手を指定しなくてはなりません。

ページの右側に[Reviewers]とあり、その右側にある歯車のマークを押すと添付画像のようにレビュワーを指定するフォームが現れます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下の公式サイトのようにManage accessでは自分のサブのGitHubアカウントをコラボレーターとして追加しています。
https://docs.github.com/ja/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

> コラボレーターとして招待する人のユーザ名を確認してください。まだユーザ名がない場合は、GitHubにサインアップできます。詳細は「新しい
> GitHubアカウントへのサインアップ」を参照してください。
>
> GitHub.comで、リポジトリのメインページにアクセスしてください。

しかしここのReviewerを追加するのに自分の作ったサブのGitHubアカウント名をタイプしてみたのですが何の反応もありません。

チーム開発をする際、レビュワーにチェックしてもらうにはこの添付画像の状態から依頼する相手をどうやって指定したら良いのでしょうか？

初心者で多少混乱しています。わかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コラボレーターとしてユーザーを追加した場合、招待したユーザー (今回の例ならサブユーザー) の登録アドレス宛に確認メールが届いていないでしょうか？

受け取った相手が了承しない限り、ユーザー追加は保留の状態になっている可能性があります。
(GitHub リポジトリの設定でコラボレーターのセクションも確認してみてください)